# Selenium Webdriver 3 unable to identify object on the standard Salesforce lookup pop-up window

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium Webdriver to automate Salesforce application through it. 
Test Scenario: - On Account page, When clicked the "Lookup"(Account) search icon opens up standard Salesforce search pop-up. I am unable to switch window.

```
    WebDriver popup=driver;
    //Click on the Search icon of Account Lookup
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("j_id0:formId:j_id29:j_id53:j_id54:3:j_id55_lkwgt"));
    String Parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> handles =  driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.err.println("No of windows :  " + handles.size());
    element.click();
    for (String s : handles){
         String windowHandle = s;
          popup = driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);

          System.out.println("Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
          System.out.println("Window Url : " + popup.getCurrentUrl());
          if (popup.getTitle().contains("Salesforce")){
              System.out.println("Selected Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
              driver = popup;
              driver.switchTo().frame("searchFrame");
              driver.findElement(By.id("lksrch")).sendKeys("Google");
              driver.switchTo().frame("resultsFrame");
              //Selecct account for search Account.
              driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Account_body']//tr[2]/th")).click();
              break;
          }

          }

    driver.switchTo().window(Parent_Window);

  return element;
```

Comment: Can you check is that Pop up an iframe or check identifying using xpath

Comment: I have Identified it is iframe.

Comment: Kindly use switchtoFrame instead of switchtoWindow

Comment: I have share my code

Comment: What is the err you are getting now?

Comment: Both the Window ID is coming as same and not able to navigate Child Window.

Comment: Can i have the complete code starting from the site url. I will check from my local

Comment: I can't Share My full code, Can you help me how can we select an account from standard salesforce lookup.I have already shared my code to switch window.It would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Move to frame using this .

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[@src='yourFrameSourceFromHTML']")));
```

This is useful when the frame doesn't have any ID.